# Mongo db find multiple conditions on the same key

Tags: mongodb, select, find, logic, selection

I encountered an unexpected behavior in find() logic on mongodb community 5.0.6.

My collection is:

```
{ _id: 1, a: 1, b: 1 }
{ _id: 2, a: 2, b: 2 }
{ _id: 3, a: 3, b: 3 }
```

when I execute

```
db.selection.find({a:1,b:2})
```

I obtain an empty set as resultset, as expected for condition a=1 AND b=2  (AND logic in selection)

But when I execute

```
db.selection.find({a:1,a:2})
```

Which should represent the logic condition a=1 AND a=2
I obtain this result

```
{ _id: 2, a: 2, b: 2 }
```

Honestly I was expecting an empty set again.
Someone can explain it?

Comment: Both queries look the same. Please check your question

Comment: Yes, I edited the second query from 
db.selection.find({a:1,b:2})
to
db.selection.find({a:1,a:2})
Now it's  correct. Thanks for advising.